# How to setup Table of Content in TiddlyWiki

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

If I go TiddlyWiki site I can see tab **Content**. How can I create my own table of content for my tiddlywiki file?

Comment: Youtuber does exactly that in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bu7JU4DjPrg&list=PLzZCajspPU_UjFn0uy-J9URz0LP4zhxRK&index=2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new tiddler and give the title **Contents**

Under tags, give the value **$:/tags/SideBar**

Under type the text for this tiddler, give
`<$list filter={{$:/core/Filters/AllTiddlers!!filter}} template="$:/core/ui/ListItemTemplate"/>`

Comment: This is great - it works in my firefox on windows, TiddlyWiki 5.1.9. Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I found the documentation for this really confusing, but here's what I did that works best:

```
<div class="tc-table-of-contents">

<<toc-selective-expandable 'TableOfContents' sort[ind]>>

</div>
```

Then, tag each tiddler with TableofContents.

Lastly, when editing each tiddler, add a new field named "ind" (for index - you can change this to whatever you like, so long as it's not being used elsewhere, of course). Assign a value to "ind" starting with 0 to tell it what order you want the tiddlers to go in. I incremented by 10 instead of 1 in case I want to rearrange a few things or insert more in the middle.

Comment: Yeah man the docs didn't make much sense at all. I'll try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is explained [in the documentation](http://tiddlywiki.com/#Table-of-Contents%20Macros).

The short version: Add some tag (e.g. `Content`) to the pages you want to appear in the TOC; then in the place where you want it to appear, use one of the macros with that tag name (e.g. `<<toc Content>>`). To make a nested TOC, tag pages with the names of tags that appeared at the top level. So for example if you have a tiddler named `First` that is tagged with `Content`, then you can tag more tiddlers with `First`, and they will appear indented below `First` in the TOC.

Comment: The docs are a bit confusing.  I am looking to generate a table of contents within a given tiddler that's very long: e.g. for its own h1s, h2s, etc.  Do you know of a way to generate a table of contents for the hierarchy like this *within a single tiddler for that single tiddler itself*?  Edit: It sounds like this may not be possible :( according to https://groups.google.com/g/tiddlywiki/c/5rosst5JqTU.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. A tiddler with a table of contents... "for the tiddler itself"? As in, it lists exactly one item, which is itself? What use is that?

Comment: As in it lists an outline of the hierarchy of that tiddler.  Like what a table of contents extension in Markdown does.  Example: https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/toc/.

Comment: I don't know a way to do that, but I would suggest that it's not how tiddlers are meant to be used anyway. Try putting less text on each; you'll be happier in the long run, since you'll have more opportunities to, e.g. make useful cross-references, include sections in categories, etc.

Comment: That approach unfortunately doesn't scale super well for this use case.  (It's hundreds of one line items that change frequently through bulk editing.)